# SMS Read/Write/Delete/Insert Android Application

Tags: android

At the moment I am trying to create an android application that would allow me to view the sms sqlite database and delete,insert, edit and view records.

Currently I have only found information regarding developing a sending and receiving sms application. Has anyone created similar applications?

Any advice on where to research, how I could tackle this application would be greatly appreciated.

Ive spend quite a while trying to find similar application that tackle what I am looking for, but I have had no luck so far.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? SO members can help you getting out of the problem you face in coding,cannot write complete code for you friend!

Comment: The [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_providers_telephonyprovider) for the actual provider is available - allowing you to see exactly what is available.